# Writing proper DSL

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin, factory, dsl, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to be able to write that calls a factory method to create an instance of a object instead of directly calling the constructor.

I have a factory named, `PersonFactory` that implements a method called `getPresonTypeOne(name: String, age:Int, address: String)`. `PersonTypeOne` has three member variables named `name`, `age`, and `address`. I want to be able to write something that calls `getPresonTypeOne` to create an instance of `PersonTypeOne` instead of directly calling the `PersonTypeOne` constructor.

I ideally what something that looks like this

```
class PersonTypeOne(
      val name: String, 
      val age: Int, 
      val address: String) {
    ...
}


personTypeOne {
    withName {
       ...
    }
    withAge {
       ...
    }
    withAddress {
       ...
    } 
}
```

I would like that DSL to get effectively result in a call that looks like this : `personFactory.getPresonTypeOne(name, age, address)`

I have looked around quite a bit, but I have only found examples of me being able to do this by directly calling the `PersonTypeOne` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what your indent is. If you only want to hide the factory call, you don't need a DSL. A function with named parameter will do the job:

```
fun personTypeOne(name: String, age: Int, address: String): PersonTypeOne =
    PersonFactory.getPersonTypeOne(name, age, address)

val person1 = personTypeOne(name = "Name", address = "address", age = 42)
```

If you really need a DSL, you need to define a builder helper class with methods for each attribute and a function to use this builder:

```
class PersonTypOneBuilder {
    private var name: String? = null
    private var age: Int? = null
    private var address: String? = null

    fun withName(name: () -> String) {
        this.name = name()
    }

    fun withAge(age: () -> Int) {
        this.age = age()
    }

    fun withAddress(address: () -> String) {
        this.address = address()
    }

    fun build() =
        PersonFactory.getPersonTypeOne(
            name ?: throw IllegalStateException(),
            age ?: throw IllegalStateException(),
            address ?: throw IllegalStateException()
        )
}

fun personTypeOne(block: PersonTypOneBuilder.() -> Unit): PersonTypeOne =
    PersonTypOneBuilder().apply(block).build()
```

Now you can use the DSL:

```
val person2 = personTypeOne {
    withName {
        "Bla"
    }
    withAddress {
        "address"
    }
    withAge {
        42
    }
}
```

Comment: @jadeblack12 Then the second solution should work. Look at the documentation for [type safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html). But you should be aware, that you have to create the builder classes and methods by yourself. Or do you see a problem with the second solution?

Comment: Yes, I believe the second solution works as well (testing it right now), but I was really hoping there was a way to achieve this without a builder.

Will mark the answer as approved in a bit after testing as this does look like it solves my problem.

Comment: I was able to do exactly what I wanted with this.